# Create 2 Column list of checkboxes using *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a list of CheckBox created from API [Single Column selection box list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkgIf.png)and want to show it in 2 columns [2 column based selection boxes list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLiWQ.png).

I have written below code to

```
<mat-card-content >
          <div fxLayout="row">
            <div fxFlex="50" *ngFor="let service of servicesList; let i = index;" >
              <mat-checkbox *ngIf= "i%2 == 0"  [disabled]="isOfferSelected" [value]="service.id" (change)="calculateServiceAmount($event,service)">{{service.serviceName}}</mat-checkbox>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="50" class="otherhalf">
              <mat-checkbox *ngIf="i%2 != 0" [disabled]="isOfferSelected" [value]="service.id" (change)="calculateServiceAmount($event,service)">{{service.serviceName}}</mat-checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>
      </mat-card-content>
```

But it didn't work out, It does create a row with some top spacing from 1st div creation.

Answer (score 0):

First, organize your "servicesList" into a multidimensional array of this sort: [[service1, service2], [service3, service4]...] whereby, each nested array has a maximum of 2 elements. The following **getter** method will help you with that:

> code.ts

```
    get reorganizedServices() {
    const noOfRows = this.servicesList.length / 2;
    const allRows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++) {
      allRows.push([...this.servicesList].splice(i * 2, 2)); // use spread operator to avoid mutation
    }
    return allRows;
  }
```

> code.html

```
<div *ngFor="let row of reorganizedServices" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let service of row">
    <div fxFlex="50">
      <mat-checkbox [disabled]="isOfferSelected" [value]="service.id" (change)="calculateServiceAmount($event,service)">{{service.serviceName}}</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you float those two divs, the content div collapses to zero height. To remove a row with some top spacing from 1st div creation.
place the below code in css, Will work :)

```
<br style="clear:both;"/>
```